Font size conflict between document class and tikzpicture
Here are my files reduces for the MWE :
file 1 :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
   
\begin{document}

\input{Chaine_Fonctionnelle}

\end{document}

file 2 :
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\input{Chaine_Fonctionnelle}
 
\end{document}

Chaine_Fonctionnelle.tex :
% \tikzset{font=\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
        \node[line width=2pt, minimum width=5cm, text width=3.8cm,minimum height=5cm, rectangle] (Ali) at (0,0) {};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (Ali.east)--(Ali.west);
        \node[font=\large\bfseries, anchor=south, above = 1cm,align=center,inner sep=-18pt] at (Ali.south) {Redresseur  \\ (pont de diodes)\\ + filtre \\ (Condensateur)};
\end{tikzpicture}
    

here is the version from the article :

here is the version from the standalone :

I've tried a few things that showed me what causes the differences. For example I can remove the 12 points from the first line of the article, then the two images look the same, but I would like a solution that doesn't imply a change at this top line.
I've tried local changes like the commented line, but to no avail.
I thought the hierarchy was putting local indication above global indication, but I can't seem to overrule that 12 point from the documentclass command.
Can you help me ?
First Edition ---------------- :
Thank you for your answers and comments, I'll try make a few changes try and avoid some problems : avoiding negative value for inner sep, for that I'll anchor the text to the middle of the line, but the problem doesn't go away :
New file Chaine_Fonctionnelle.tex :
% \tikzset{font=\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,line width=2pt, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=4.2cm, rectangle] (Ali) at (0,0) {};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (Ali.east)--(Ali.west) node[midway] (MidAli) {};
        \node[font=\large\bfseries, anchor=north, align=center] at (MidAli) {Redresseur  \\ (pont de diodes)\\ + filtre \\ (Condensateur)};
\end{tikzpicture}

Here are the result, first from the standalone then from the article compilation :


You can see the two compilations still give different results.

you have specified a fixed amount of over print inner sep=-18pt that is always liable to cause the text to overprint the surrounding material depending on the spacing where it is included.

@david-carlisle Thanks you for your comment, I have edited my question to provide a version without the negative inner sep , but there is still a difference between the standalone compilation and the article one.

well you are using article at 12pt and standalone at 10pt so naturally you have different size fonts

@david-carlisle , I would like to add a parameter to my tikzpicture included in both document so that it does not depend on the document general font size.

why? everything about the text in the tikz depends on the document settings, the font the text style, baseline spacing, not just the font size.

because I intend to produce tikzpictures that I can use in different documents without having to tweak the dimensions and positioning everytime I include it.

well as I say you can use \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont to ensure 10pt, but the use case seems very weird, the main point of standalone is to produce such a tikz image that does not depend on document setting that you can then include with \includegraphics why use standalone to make a standalone image if you are re-using the source rather than the rendered form?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try using the following instead. This code uses the positioning library and places the node below the centre of the reference node, rather than above its bottom. It dispenses with the inner sep specification.
Note that scale=0.8 is doing nothing whatsoever. Try scale=0.1 and notice that the standalone image has precisely the same dimensions.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-1.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.8] this has no effect
  \node[line width=2pt, minimum width=5cm, text width=3.8cm,minimum height=5cm, rectangle] (Ali) at (0,0) {};
  \draw[line width=2pt] (Ali.east)--(Ali.west);
  \node[font=\large\bfseries, anchor=north, below =.25cm of Ali.center,align=center]  {Redresseur\\(pont de diodes)\\+ filtre\\(Condensateur)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\input{\jobname-1}
\end{document}

EDIT
From my comment at the request of the OP.
One of the main advantages of using tikz/pgf or similar is that it ensures the fonts and spacing in your diagrams are consistent with those in the document.
There is no practical way to make such diagrams independent of the surrounding environment. To do that you'd have to essentially do class and package setup inside the tikzpicture. But a major reason to use \input (and TikZ) is to ensure the picture is sensitive to the context e.g. that the fonts are consistent with those used in the document, that the size of skips and font-dependent dimensions such as em and ex match etc.
If that's not what you want, compile your images separately and use \includegraphics. If you don't want the context-sensitivity, there's no disadvantage to \includegraphics. That's often the right choice for things like logos, but generally sub-optimal for things like diagrams.

Thank you for answering. scale does not visibly change this MWE but it does change the whole figure, some features are impacted by scale and not others.
I use positioning to put the text in the bottom half part of a rectangle (that is cut in half by the line), and I use the inner sep to adjust the vertical position when the text has several lines instead of one. Using the center of the rectangle instead of the bottom as reference point would just move the problem.
I'm looking for a solution that would give the same result for the tikzpicture in the standalone and in the article.

@LMT-PhD It doesn't just move the problem. It illustrates a more fruitful strategy for positioning. Making inner sep negative is inviting trouble. You are much more likely to get consistent results with a strategy which doesn't rely on that kind of manipulation. Very occasionally, that kind of adjustment is useful to create a special effect (overlapping) or to provide a quick fix for a problem you don't have the time and/or inclination to fix properly. But it will have all kinds of side-effects e.g. it may mess up the bounding box.

@LMT-PhD scale doesn't change this example, so it isn't necessary in your minimised code. I didn't mean to suggest it doesn't make any difference to anything. But you don't need it here. If my particular suggestion doesn't work, there are other sane strategies e.g. use a split node or (possibly overkill) a matrix or two nodes or whatever. The point is to avoid having to fudge things with the kind of adjustments that cause trouble. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720516/font-size-conflict-between-document-class-and-tikzpicture/720541?noredirect=1#comment1792113_720516.

thanks again @cfr , I have tried to edit my question to provide a version without the negative inner sep , by positioning the text relatively to the center of the line. But there is still a difference between the standalone compilation and the article one.

@LMT-PhD Are you asking how to standardise the font size? Add 12pt to the options for standalone if you want the same size fonts in both pictures.

I would like the change to be in my tikzpicture included (to create a figure not depending on its surroundings) rather than in the standalone. @cfr

Thank you cfr I've discussed with david-carlisle and it seems there are no way to meet all my requirements. So if you conclude as well that there is no way of making the font in the input independent from the document around, could you sum it up in a conclusion to your answer including your last comment remarks so that I can mark it as solved ? Thank you for your help

@LMT-PhD - Done.
